# Android textClock stretch to screen width and height

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, clock

I am new to android programming.  I am trying to create a basic clock app. I have found the textClock function and have been trying to implement it such that the clock digits stretch to the width of the screen or parent view.  Right now when I put in a text clock and define a textSize, the clock looks huge on a nexus 4 and small on a nexus 10.

How to I make the clock stretch to the screen width?

Any help is appreciated. If you provide code, please explain it in detail. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by changing font size dynamically.

you should create a custom widget for it.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds) is a very helpful link that shows you how to do this!

---

[TextClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html) is a widget that extends `TextView`. you should create your own `TextClock` for your purpose. in above link, there is sample code for a custom widget that you want.

Comment: I am confused a bit by the link. I am not creating a Widget. I am trying to create an application that is a clock app. Based on that link, it will autosize textView but not the textClock.

Answer (score 0):

Try to some thing like below
`<TextClock  android:id="@+id/textClock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide us some code? I can think of several reasons: the layout width, "dp" or "sp" missing after the number... Code will be helpful